# Align a group of views containing a chain in a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have three views in a ConstraintLayout and want to align then like this:

[image]

Right now views **B** and **C** form a vertical chain, and **A** is centered relative to the chain. But how do I align the entire group centered in the parent? Note that View **C** may be `GONE`.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a visual answer without nesting layouts.

[image]

#### Steps

1. [Chain and pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639504/android-studio-layout-editor-constraintlayout-pack-vs-chain) B and C vertically
2. Chain and pack A and C horizontally
3. Align B and C horizontal centers
4. Center A vertically

#### XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:background="#fb0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:background="#2000ff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="B"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="187dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:background="#f1a500"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="C"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### Personal opinion

Switch to [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/). The layout is much easier than ConstraintLayout.

Comment: If view C might be `GONE`, then I think it would be easiest to wrap B and C in a `LinearLayout` and then do the rest of the layout with constraints. That would also solve the potential problem where B is wider than C.

Comment: Its really awesome

Comment: Thanks for a clear visual explanation.
*Could you please point a guide explaining how to accomplish this through XML-design?*
(I could, ofcourse, repeat the actions you demonstrate above, and examine the resulting XML, but I'm looking for a generic, thorough explanation).

Comment: @Bliss, sorry I don't have one at the moment. If you make one feel free to add another answer or edit this one.

Comment: It is much harder to follow this that to simply look at the XML code in the layout.