# Android Studio Layout Editor ConstraintLayout: pack vs chain

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, graphical-layout-editor

In the Android Studio Layout Editor I see the words "pack" and "chain" with respect to a `ConstraintLayout`. I know they both have something to do with multiple views being connected to each other in a line, but their difference is not clear to me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

What is the difference between "pack" and "chain"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Short answer

A **Chain** is a group of views that are bound together in a vertical or horizontal line. **Pack** means that the views should be kept very closely together, ie, touch each other (excluding any padding).

## Pack

Pack means that the views are packed tightly together. Imagine that you are packing your clothes tightly together in a suitcase before going on a trip.

[image]

Points to note:

- You can pack views horizontally or vertically.
- Packing doesn't in itself doesn't constrain the views to each other.

  - If they are not already chained, then packing moves their absolute position in the Layout Editor so that they are adjacent to each other. 
    [image]
  - If they are chained, then setting the Chain mode to `packed` binds them closely together.

    ```
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    ```

    [image]

## Chain

A chain occurs when two adjacent views both have constraints to each other. Imagine an iron link chain.

[image]

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain) shows this well.

[image]

This chain can continue where every link (view) in the chain has a two-way link to its neighbors.

[image]

**Chain mode/style**

As I briefly mentioned above, there are different modes or styles for a chain. They are shown below *(image from [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-chain))*.

1. Spread (default)
2. Spread inside
3. Weighted
4. Packed

[image]

All of these are **chained**. Only the bottom one is **packed**.